# Ubuntu 20.04 cannot keep apps open after resume

Tags: suspend, swap

Recently i installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Asus n550jk laptop. And I have an issue. When I suspend my laptop, it seems to work, because it will turn on when I open the lid or press any key, but apps that were open, now are closed. I tried to add more swap (now it is 16GB - laptop's RAM is 12BGB) and uncomment

```
 HandleSuspendKey=suspend  
 HandleLidSwitch=suspend  
 HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
```

in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file, but nothing changed. It's like it was turned off.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue I remember having on an HP a few years back. This is how I solved it:

1. Create a file as root named `/etc/acpi/lid.sh`
   For example, in a terminal: `sudo vi /etc/acpi/lid.sh`
2. Paste the following into the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
/usr/sbin/pm-suspend
fi
```

3. Make the file executable with: `sudo chmod +x /etc/acpi/lid.sh`

This should solve your problem.

Comment: can't find `/etc/acpi/local/lid.sh.post` directory. is it ok or should be a directory ? i think if i create directory and file would't work.

Comment: The directory name is `/etc/acpi/local`, the file name is `lid.sh.post` 

Comment: yeah i know but no `/etc/acpi/local` directory exist :)

Comment: My bad, I was using an older version of Ubuntu to test. For 20.04 you'll need to use `/etc/acpi` as the directory, `lid.sh` as the file. I'll update the answer.

Comment: unfortunately your solution didn't work :(